# How to view someone elses data (owned by them) in my calendar

Tags: sharing, roles, calendar, ownership

I can create a calendar my records I own but not my teams.
How can I see my teams activities in my calendar.

Answer (score 1):

1. You must have read access to the specific data;
2. Be above in the Role hierarchy with "Grant Access Using Hierarchies" turned on;
3. Ensure 1 or 2 datetime fields on the object. Preference is to have 2 fields (Start-End);
4. Create a list view of the required data on the object in question (Task object);
5. Use the "My Teams Tasks" option within the List view filter - See Pic;
6. Create a new calendar - See Pic;
7. select the object in question;
8. select the start and end datetime fields;
9. select the list view you just created;
10. Save - Done!
    [image]
    [image]

Other object are harder because you have to isolate the data specifically in the list view.
essentially the calendar is a graphical representation of a list view.

When trying to filter on your team Aliases is good, I always setup everyone with FirstName Last initial e.g. JohnS.
Or better yet if you can filter by your business Unit.